# Lock items width and height on window size change

Tags: html, css

I found a site that has exactly what I'm looking for If we change the size of the window on which we are, the items stay in their place and do not adapt.

What is the css property that does this please.

Website : https://rustypot.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent div from moving while resizing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841845/prevent-div-from-moving-while-resizing-the-page)

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you require as that site certainly does adapt to the actual viewport.

Comment: I wanted to fix the position and the size of the elements but in the end I just changed the vw and vh by px ^^

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this property**

```
.div{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: the website is not using `vh`. Using `vh` compress your height! forcing it to stay in viewport.