# HTML Prevent moving objects (div's) on window resize

Tags: html, css

**Info:** using Chrome Version 29.0.1547.62 m, and IE Version 7.0.6002.18005

I've tried searching SO and Google, but never really found an answer that works, whether it's not being applied properly by me (tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745923/prevent-div-moving-on-window-resize) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534123/prevent-div-block-from-moving-when-window-resized)), or not quite answering the same question I'm asking...

I'm making a very simple site being used internally on a network. My only problem is when I resize the window below the value of the iFrame `#calcframe {min-width:510px}` + div `#panel {width:186px}`, the `calcframe` gets shifted below the panel.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <STYLE>
          body {font-family:'Arial'; font-size:90%}
          html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0}
          #panel {background:black; color:white; width:186px; height: calc(100% - 75px); float:left}
          #content {height: calc(100% - 75px)}
          #spacer {background:black; font-size:400%; color:white ; height:75px}
          #calcFrame {height: calc(100% - 3px); width: calc(100% - 186px); min-width:510px; margin:0; padding:0}
        </STYLE>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
          function OpenHTML(cC) {
            document.getElementById("cF").src=cC + ".html"
            }
        </SCRIPT>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
        <div id='spacer'>
          SC
        </div>
        <div id='panel'>
          <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='L' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">L<br>
          <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='U' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">U<br>
          <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='D' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">D<br>
          <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='P' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">P<br>
        </div>
        <div id='content'>
          <iframe id='cF' frameborder="0")></iframe>
        </div>
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Please be gentle :), I'm self-taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the items you dont want resized into a div let call it "wrapper". Then set the min-width on "wrapper" to lets say 510px. anything inside of this div container should not be changed.
Also, try to keep the html markup in lowercase. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
          body {font-family:'Arial'; font-size:90%}
          html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0}
          #panel {background:black; color:white; width:186px; height: calc(100% - 75px); float:left}
          #content {height: calc(100% - 75px)}
          #spacer {background:black; font-size:400%; color:white ; height:75px}
          #calcFrame {height: calc(100% - 3px); width: calc(100% - 186px); margin:0; padding:0}
          #wrapper {min-width: 510px;}
        </style>
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
          function OpenHTML(cC) {
            document.getElementById("cF").src=cC + ".html"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id='spacer'>
                SC
            </div>
            <div id='panel'>
                <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='L' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">L<br>
                <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='U' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">U<br>
                <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='D' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">D<br>
                <input type='radio' name='CalcType' id='P' onClick="OpenHTML(this.id)">P<br>
            </div>
            <div id='content'>
                <iframe id='cF' frameborder="0")></iframe>
            </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks so much! Out of curiosity, is there a reason to keep the markup in lcase? Or just standard convention?

Comment: Convention and browser support. Chrome and Firefox should accept it but lowercase is how its done at least in HTML 4

Answer (score 1):

this might work

```
<div> 
   <div id='panel'> </div> 
   <div id='content'> </div> 
</div>
```

and make #panel float:left

Comment: I tried using float and such, but I couldn't end up getting the combinations right... but thanks for the input!